# substitute variable in awk command

Tags: xml, awk, xml-parsing, substitution

I am using and awk command to update tag in an xml. below is the tag in xml file

```
<ApplicationURL>http://localhost.com</ApplicationURL>
```

my awk command is like

```
$appurl=http://remotehost.com

awk -F'<|>' '/<ApplicationURL>[^<>]+<\/ApplicationURL>/{sub($3,"$appurl")}1'  myxml.xml
```

my output is not replacing the variable. it directly takes it as string. Can you please tell where I am going wrong.

Output:

```
<ApplicationURL>$appurl</ApplicationURL>
```

desired output should replace the variable value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appurl=http://remotehost.com

use internal variable. Option `-v` allow to assign a variable at command line

```
awk -F'<|>' -v "MyVar=${appurl}" '/<ApplicationURL>[^<>]+<\/ApplicationURL>/{sub($3,MyVar)}1'  myxml.xml
```

Comment: there is one issue with the above command line.  It does not update the tags if the tags are empty. if there is some value between the tags it will work.

Comment: try changing `[^<>]+` with  `[^<>]*`